# Auto email SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have one parameter report that I want to send out email with the parameter value for 'ALL'. If I assign a default value 'All' to the parameter, the auto email works well but we use the same report file on our UI for clients to enter parameter value to pull the report. This way we don't want the report pop out automatically with all records.

Do I have to create a separate SSRS file to assign the default value then I can auto email the report?

Comment: Is the email a subscription based report?

Comment: What do you mean with "auto email"?. I don't understand what is your problem. You can set the default value "All" to send report by default with all records and you can still filter the report through the available values in the report.

Comment: yes, the problem is every time you click the report link on UI, the report will pop out directly with all data first which takes a long time normally. So we don't want to give default value to the parameter but this way the email can not send out correctly.

Comment: When you say "UI" do you mean the Report Server website or are you surfacing the report in a custom application?

Comment: Mike, it is a custom application. We want to use the same SSRS file on the application screen for clients to choose the parameter value then pop out the report. at well as allow clients to edit email address for auto email. but now the default value set up can only satisfy one purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In the report design, make sure this parameter does not have a default value.
But when you create the subscrpiption, you can select  'ALL' as the default value.
This will not interfere with the report's behavior when it is run manually.
When users run the report on demand, they will still need to select a value.
Hope this helps.